# What is "Disjoint line segments"?

Tags: geometry

I'm unable to find a definition for disjoint line segments.

Can someone please define it and if possible show images with examples?

Comment: I think it might just mean "non-intersecting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out from the context of the problem.

It means that the line segments do not touch each other at all, neither through intersection nor at their ends.

In other words: They don't have any common points.